# Use of padding in GaussianFilter

Tags: filtering, padding

I understand from the help that `Padding->None` is a valid option for `GaussianFilter[]`

> With a setting Padding->None, GaussianFilter[data,...] normally returns an array, audio or image smaller than data.  »

Yet when I try to use it, I get unexpected results, first without padding:

```
In[.]:= GaussianFilter[DiskMatrix[1, 3], 1]

Out[216]= {{1., 1., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}, {1., 1., 1.}}
```

and then with padding

```
In[.]:= GaussianFilter[DiskMatrix[1, 3], 1, Padding -> None]

Out[.]= {{0.811116 + 0.188884 None, 0.90062 + 0.0993805 None, 
  0.811116 + 0.188884 None}, {0.90062 + 0.0993805 None, 1., 
  0.90062 + 0.0993805 None}, {0.811116 + 0.188884 None, 
  0.90062 + 0.0993805 None, 0.811116 + 0.188884 None}}
```

I don't understand what is wrong and why my case doesn't fall under "normally returns an array smaller than data"

using 12.0

Comment: It looks like a documentation bug. What the documentation says is correct for 2D data, but they forget to mention that it works differently for 1D data.

Comment: I tried a 2D input, I seem to get same result (updated main question)

Comment: Looks like a real bug: it really shouldn't be padding with the symbol "None". It kind of works in 2D if you replace None with a number (like 0 to mean pad with zero).

Comment: @bills Well, it's fixed padding, so it pads with whatever padding you give it. Symbols, numbers, it's kind of the same thing in WL. It's the same in 1D and 2D.

Comment: @Anatoly I was thinking of images, there's an example of that under Options -> Padding in the documentation.